# IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory MongoDB in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, access-control, ubuntu-20.04

I have just installed mongodb on my remote ubuntu server for using it with an angular and nodejs project. I created a user using the db.createUser command along with password and roles in the mongo shell.

Then when i try to start the mongodb instance with access control using the command:

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

its displaying the error:

```
IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory MongoDB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, have you checked the permissions of the folder `/var/lib/mongodb` (`ls -l /var/lib`)?

The folder and its contents should be assigned to the `mongod` user. You could also check the ACL permissions (`getfacl`), if that's installed in your system.

If permissions seem correct, please continue reading to know how I solved the same error in a different environment.

---

This happened to me in CentOS 8 after a wrong reinstallation of MongoDB and the data folder `/var/lib/mongo` had to be created manually. In my case, the problem was that the security context of SELinux (https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/what-is-selinux) had to be updated to give `mongod` access the folder.

The command below solved my problem *(note the path to the data folder in my configuration is slightly different, just update it for your case)*:

```
chcon -Rv --type=mongod_var_lib_t /var/lib/mongo
```

It basically tells SELinux that the context used by MongoDB to access the files should be associated with the target folder.

You can have more information about `chcon` here: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chcon.1.html

Comment: This answer pointed me to the correct path, `/var/lib/mongodb`, with two differences:
1) My user was `mongodb` not `mongod`; 2) I changed both group and user ownership with the following line: `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

Comment: You sir are a Prince!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!